# Rsync files-from problem

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -av --files-from=list.txt A/* B/
```

Inside the list.txt I have

```
A/text1.txt
```

When executing the command, I get an error refering me to the man page, does anyone know why?

Please see the rsync(1) and rsyncd.conf(5) man pages for full documentation
See http://rsync.samba.org/ for updates, bug reports, and answers
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(854)

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing rsync by including directories on the command line and in the file, and by having the wildcard.  This may be more what you want:

```
$ cat lists.txt 
text1.txt

$ ls A
text1.txt  toskip.txt

$ rsync -av --files-from=lists.txt A/ B/
building file list ... done
created directory B
text1.txt

sent 89 bytes  received 31 bytes  240.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ ls B
text1.txt
```

So `lists.txt` only includes the filenames and not the directory, and on the command line you specify the source directory `A`.  We can see it only copied the file listed in the `lists.txt` file and skipped the other one.